# Cancel completion block after delay

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

There is block that discovering CBServices of some CBPeripheral (CoreBluetooth). But how can I cancel this block after some time has passed?

For example, if it has not discover CBServices after 10 seconds my block must be cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use performSelector for delay action

```
[self performSelector:@selector(cancelAction:) withObject:self afterDelay:10];

-(void)cancelAction:(id)sender {

    //What ever you want try here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call stopScan function of CBCentralManager.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stopScan:) withObject:self afterDelay:10];

- (void)stopScan:(id)sender {
    [self.centralManager stopScan];
}
```

Comment: it worked, but in my case in method stopScan: I need to set completion handler to nil.

Comment: then you can have a block variable which you can set as a parameter to CBCentralManager and you can set this block to nil.